# How do I run the tests in the Facebook folly library?

Tags: folly

I've downloaded and built the Facebook Folly code on my Ubuntu 20.04.02 system. I built and installed googletest, and made sure to use the CMake flag `-DBUILD_TESTS=ON` to enable building the tests.

But how do I run the tests? I've looked around the build and source tree, don't see anything obvious. Google didn't help, either.

When I run `make test` in the `_build` directory, I get

```
$ make test
Running tests...
Test project /home/chad/f14/folly/_build
No tests were found!!!
```